# Как вытащить текст из созданной мною переменной телеграмм бота?

Tags: python, функции, бот, telebot

Прошу помочь, в этой строчке кода я пытаюсь вытащить текст из переменной messagetextic но мне выводит <function messagetextic at 0x7f2dd3dceb00>
`bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f'{messagetextic}', reply_markup=markup)`
Прошу помогите не могу решить проблему.

вот код:

```
def messagetextic(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Выполни следующие действие', url='vk.com')
    markup.add(button1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text, reply_markup=markup)
def messagetextic2(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton( message.text, url='vk.com')
    markup.add(button1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f'{messagetextic}', reply_markup=markup)
def messagetextic3(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'сделай следующие действие')
```

Comment: У вас messagetextic - это не переменная, а функция (у вас это написано в 1 строчке). Поэтому так и получается.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Создание URL кнопок телеграмм ботом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1456808/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-url-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc)